# Mod_jk mounting all requests to tomcat except of two sites

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I'm using mod_jk to make a java web application accessible through an apache webserver. My vhost.conf looks like this:

```
JkMount /web/* worker1
JkMount /group/* worker1
JkMount /home/* worker1
JkMount /contact/* worker1
JkMount /customers/* worker1
JkMount /downloads/* worker1
JkMount /theme/* worker1
JkMount /language/* worker1
JkMount /image/* worker1
JkMount /layouttpl/* worker1
```

As you can see, I have to mount each site of the java web application extra. I can not just use JkMount /* worker1 because there are some PHP applications (mydomain.com/forum and mydomain.com/wiki) which are running on the same apache server. My problem is, that the names of the different sites from the tomcat server changes often. So everytime when the name of a site changes, I have to adjust the vhost.conf file.
Is there any possibility to send all requests to the tomcat server like with JkMount /* worker1 but except of /wiki and /forum?

I'm searching for something like this:

```
JkMount /* worker1
JkUnmount /forum
JkUnmount /wiki
```

Comment: Consider submitting your answer as an answer and marking this question 'solved'. That way others can see your solution more easily.

Comment: Ok, that was stupid. It seems that I answered my question by my self. There is really an JkUnMount command. But this dont work: ` JkMount /* worker1
JkUnmount /forum
JkUnmount /wiki `

Comment: That's another comment. ;) Answer box is a little further down. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
JkMount /* worker1
JkUnMount /forum/*  worker1
JkUnMount /wiki/*   worker1
```

Answer (score 2):

This way should work for those still looking:

```
JkMount /* ajp13_worker

SetEnvIf Request_URI "/forum/*" no-jk
```